# Find the number of bytes that begin with 10 or end with 01.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> A sequence of digits where each digit is 0 or 1 is called a $binary\
> \> number$. Each digit in a binary number of a component of the number. A
>   binary number with eight components is called a byte. Find the number
>   of bytes that begin with 10 or end with 01.

I start with the binary numbers that start with 10, but don't end in 01.

$$10000001$$ $$10000000$$ $$10000011$$

The first two digits are fixed. The middle 4 digits have two possibilities each, so $2^4 = 16$. The final two digits have three possibilities, $00,\ 11,$ and$\ 10$. So $(16)(3) = 48$, the number of bytes that begin with 10 but don't end with 01.

Then, I do the binary numbers that don't start with 10.
$$11000001$$ $$00000001$$ $$01000001$$
The last two digits are fixed, so following the same logic as above, $(16)(3) = 48$, the number of bytes that end with 01 but don't begin with 10.

Now, this is where I am stuck. I tried $48+48 = 96$, but the answer is 112.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot numbers that start with 10 and end with 01 - 10xxxx01 - it give you 16 numbers. 96 + 16 = 112

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the meaning of or.

Comment: You treated OR as [XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor). `A xor B` means `A or B but not both at the same time`.